# How to get EditText value into Database in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to get edit text value into database in Andorid, right now it is giving blank and in list it is printing my project path and string value @4100dd00.

here is my code.

```
public class Add_Task_List extends Activity {
EditText edt_addtasklist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task_list);
    SaveTaskList();
}

public void SaveTaskList(){

    edt_addtasklist = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_addtasklist);
    String taskliststitle = edt_addtasklist.getText().toString();
```

//how to get edittext value and store in database. right now it is creating field in db but not showing any value when I am checking in data/data/project path/database/.

```
    edt_addtasklist.setText(taskliststitle);
    System.out.println(taskliststitle);
    TaskManager_Database db = new TaskManager_Database(this);
    db.AddTaskLists(taskliststitle);    //database method
}
```

}

List Adapter:

```
 ListView list_tasklistname = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_tasklistname);
    TaskManager_Database db = new TaskManager_Database(getApplicationContext());
    list = db.GetAddTaskLists();
    ArrayAdapter<TaskDetailsActivity> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TaskDetailsActivity>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    list_tasklistname.setAdapter(adapter);
```

//it is showing list on task added in database but value is like this in one row "com.android.todotask.taskdetailsActivity@4100dee86".

I want when user enter edit text value then it store in sql database table db.AddTaskLists(taskliststitle); and show in a list where I will call db.GetAddTaskLists(); method from database.

Please let me know how to store value in sqlite db, thanks

Comment: Can you post here complete code..?

Comment: Not enough information :S

Comment: Please add your code. on how you are adding the value to the database

Comment: code s in from of you. list db.GetAddTaskLists(); this is database object and method I am calling in activity.